# Failing to remove event listener from different scope

Tags: javascript, firefox, event-listener

I try to make an add-on for Firefox 29+ (Australis). 
I have a menu item, on which I attach an event listener on opening 
of each window. 
I do it the standard way, like this:

```
var menuItem = document.getElementById("menuItemId");
if(menuItem) {
   menuItem.addEventListener("click", function onClick() {
       menuItem.removeEventListener("click", onClick, false);
       // my code here;
   }, false);
};
```

It works fine. However, my problem has as follows:

In some cases, I want to remove the listener when entering in customization mode ("about:customizing"), which is a different scope. Of course, to load my script in this mode, i have also applied my overlay.xul in "about:customizing" uri.

To remove the listener from this mode, I have tried the following:

```
WindowMediator.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser")
.document.getElementById("menuItemId")
.removeEventListener("click", onClick, false);

- or -

Window.top

- or - 

window.parent 

etc
```

I have no luck with the above methods and some other similar :-(

Any ideas?

Comment: The `onClick` reference to function in the top example won't be accessible outside that function if that's what you're trying to do. I would imagine you'd need to make it a global variable and access it from that window.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your answer. 
I will examine your suggestion, although i believe this is not 
the problem.

Comment: Hi again cookie monster, 

You are right, the onClick is not accessible outside that function
(i get undefined error). 
I modified the code properly, but however, my problem persists. 
After the modification, it works the same in main firefox windows, 
but i can't remove the listener from customisation mode 
("about:customizing"), without this time to get the undefined error. 

Probably this is because the listener is added by the main window, 
while the customisation mode has a different scope. 

Any other suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what the issue might be. Maybe in the main window where the handler is bound try creating a global function that removes the listener so that it's using the original `removeEventListener` method from the original window. Then invoke that function from the other window. `WindowMediator.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser").removeMyHandler();`